# Why is it hard to find my most recently asked question on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: support, user-interface

I often ask a question on a network site, and come back a bit later wanting to re-read it.  If it has had engagement I can find it in the in-tray, but if not I don't know where to look. I just spent a while looking for it on my account screen on Stack Exchange, but I couldn't find it, and I didn't want to navigate to the specific network site to keep looking.

To be clear, I may well be being a dumb user here, but this is not the first time I've found trying to do this frustrating.

Answer (score 9):

It's not that hard. You can find all your activity by going to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), and choosing the activity tab. Then, you can filter for posts and get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I missed that link.  I feel that it might be worth having it be a bit more noticeable, as I feel it's a higher usage action than others at the same UI priority level.

Comment: Just a contrary position @Omroth - I never look at my Activity tab, so for me it is one of the lowest usage actions. Everybody is different, so I guess SE look across the whole community to understand the overall priorities (that is a guess, though)